# how I can load a model to multipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

please y have been trying to show the table in the form, but I have not been able to do.
please clone and create database and run the project on github. 
is too much code to paste here.

github: https://github.com/mattisbmx/django-multipleChoiceField

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from multiselect.fields import ManyToManyField

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    funciones = ManyToManyField(Choice)
    passwd = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.pk)
```

View:

```
def index(request):
    data = {'form': forms.SelectForm()}

    return render_to_response("multiselect/index.html", data,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request
```

Form:

```
class SelectForm(forms.Form):
    data = (('1', 'One'), ('2', 'Two'), ('3', 'Three'), ('4', 'Four')) #<--I think here I load the data model
    choices = MultipleChoiceField(choices=data)
```

Thanks

Comment: Does [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ModelMultipleChoiceField`

```
class SelectForm(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Choice.objects.all()) #Replace the queryset with the queryset of your choice.
```

If you wish to change the default widget

You can use `widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple()` or whichever you wish.